# Converting multiple IIfs when converting from MS Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server `case` statements. How would I convert when I have multiple IIFs?

```
IIF((P.GM_CD=6150 Or P.GM_CD>=12100),
     IIF(GameXrefVar.DCLBGame = null, P.GM_VAR.GameXrefVar.DCLBGame,P.GM_VAR.GameXrefVar.DCLBGame) AS GameID,
```

Comment: The parentheses don't balance.

Comment: The first thing to know is they are a `case` *expression* not a *statement* i.e. they return a value not an expression.

Comment: Actually, SQL Server 2012+ supports [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)!

Answer (score 1):

The *standard* `case` expression is what you should just always use.  Presumably you intend:

```
(CASE WHEN (P.GM_CD = 6150 OR P.GM_CD >= 12100) AND GameXrefVar.DCLBGame IS null
      THEN P.GM_VAR.GameXrefVar.DCLBGame
      WHEN (P.GM_CD = 6150 Or P.GM_CD >= 12100) THEN P.GM_VAR.GameXrefVar.DCLBGame
 END) AS GameID,
```

`= NULL` never evaluates to true, so it doesn't do anything particularly useful.

Comment: I dnt think i sent the column statement from access. When I edit my code for the solution I still get errors. THis is what Im actually trying to convert  :  IIf(IsNull([GameXrefVar]![DCLBGame]),[LOTOSMIS_RET_DAILY]![GM_VAR],
 [GameXrefVar]![DCLBGame]),IIf(IsNull([GameXref]![DCLBGame]),[LOTOSMIS_RET_DAILY]![GM_CD],[GameXref]![DCLBGame])) AS GameID,

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong.

1. Parenthesis are not balanced
2. The condition value is the same in both the case.

P.GM_VAR.GameXrefVar.DCLBGame
P.GM_VAR.GameXrefVar.DCLBGame

```
CASE WHEN (P.GM_CD = 6150 OR P.GM_CD >= 12100) AND GameXrefVar.DCLBGame IS NULL
      THEN P.GM_VAR.GameXrefVar.DCLBGame END AS GameID
```

Comment: the actual msaccess column.